# useNavigate, react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть код.и при нажатии кнопки навигация срабатывает.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
 
const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate("/home");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go Home</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App
```

Почему навигация не срабатывает при

```
return (
        navigate("/home");
      );
```

Без всякой кнопки, тесть как например сделать ридирект по таймеру?

Comment: `useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => navigate('/home'), [])`

Comment: Спасибо, _______________________!